# Keep Android Fragments in Backstack

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm working on android fragments and i am unable to keep the fragments in backstack i-e when i press back button it pushes me out of the Activity which starts fragments, i want to go back to previous fragment on backpress.

So far i have tried this but i am unable to keep the fragments in backstack.

```
getActivity().getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
             .replace(R.id.mainContainer, searchResultsFragment)
             .addToBackStack(null)
             .commit();
```

Comment: thanks bro for down-voting it really helped without suggesting anything :/

Comment: this not me who voting , but why he did this , cause you must search before post question , any way your question is easy I will answer it

Comment: @MinaFawzy i did searched alot but i was unable to find anything so i finally i had to ask here!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

before you call `commit()`  to commit transaction, you should add fragment to backstack `addToBackStack(null)` as you did in your provided code

then override `onBackPressed()` to pop fragment from stack

the issue you facing , you make your transaction with `FragmentManager`

```
getActivity().getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
             .replace(R.id.mainContainer, searchResultsFragment)
             .addToBackStack(null)
             .commit();
```

but you in onBackPressed() you using `SupportFragmentManager`

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0 ) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();         
    }
}
```

to fix your issue , you must know what you match your fragment type (in your case searchResultsFragment) I mean if its extend Fragment or support Fragment

in case you extend fragment support

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
```

you should use `getSupportFragmentManager()` in both transaction and onBackPressed

in case you use fragment

```
import android.app.Fragment;
```

you should use `getFragmentManager()` in both transaction and onBackPressed

Comment: thanks for your help i will try and then will tell you here

Comment: i did as you told me to override onBackPressed and as other answer gave the sample code, but "fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount()" is always returning "0"

Comment: try add executePendingTransactions () after or before commit

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97169/discussion-between-tahir-and-mina-fawzy).

Answer (score 3):

You have to overwrite onBackPressed in your activity. It is not enough only adding the fragment to back stack.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    if(fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount() != 0) {
        fragmentManager.popBackStack();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer i will check it and then will inform you here

Comment: fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount() is always returning "0"

Comment: with .addToBackstack(null) ?

Answer (score 0):

I just remove this line:

```
.addToBackStack(null)
```

And works for me.